# What are the technical differences between Windows Vista and Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the technical differences between Windows Vista and Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/269690/what-are-the-technical-differences-between-windows-vista-and-windows-7)

Where I can find the technical differences between Windows Vista and Windows 7?

I want a list of details that makes up the differences between these two OS.This is from the inside meaning process management, all the core operations.

Comment: How can this be a duplicate when i posted this question  in 2010 and the one above was asked in 2011. Perhaps I left to much time without visiting but come on!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check out the ArsTechnica [review of Windows 7](http://arstechnica.com/microsoft/reviews/2009/10/windows-7-the-review.ars).