# Windows 7 vs Vista, today?

Tags: windows

When Vista first came out it sucked really hard but nowadays it's alot better. It's hard to tell the difference between Win 7 and Vista. I can't really see any difference.

Is Vista and Win 7 nowadays pretty much the same OS or should I update to Win 7?

Comment: they both work more or less correctly, now (which is very differant from vista's initial state), but that (nor that they both run Areo themes) is no reason to say they are the same OS. they are in fact quite different under the hood.

Comment: Windows 7 is pretty much the most ideal choice between Windows 7 and Windows 8 at the moment. And there is a big difference between vista and Windows 7. Also, a possible duplicate over here: http://superuser.com/questions/269690/what-are-the-technical-differences-between-windows-vista-and-windows-7

Comment: @FrankThomas Windows 7 is 99% Vista with a lot of tweaks... We are talking about NT 6.0 to 6.1...

Comment: kernel != OS. yes they use a similar kernel (though 99% is likely not true, nor is it externally verifiable), but so did win2k and XP, which had very different user-land implementations.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer would be to **update to windows 7**.Windows 7 is the next best thing to XP.

Comment: "Windows 7 was the next best thing Microsoft ever made after XP." Is this English?

Comment: @AthomSfere I rewrote it.I hope its ok now.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 has better performance, and the security overall is better not to mention it is much more user friendly and much more reliable that the previous Windows Operating Systems. Windows 7 in my opinion is a much better OS than Vista or XP. But than again in my opinion Windows 8 is even more better.

[image: Microsoft Report Confirms Lower Infection Rate On Windows 7]

> Microsoft Report Confirms Lower Infection Rate On Windows 7 [from
>   2010]. This data has been normalized so that it represents infections
>   per thousand systems.

Comment: Wait, hold on... Vista is actually MORE secure with its use of UAC. With 7 they made it slightly less secure to let those that hated UAC see less of it.

Comment: @AthomSfere, are you referring to the difference between WFP and WRP? I agree WFP is the more secure paradigm, but its so rigid that many folks had unresolvable issues that even experts were unable to repair. The dream and the reality never coalesced.

Comment: @AthomSfere how exactly is Vista more secure than Windows 7 ? Vista had this annoying UAC that warned you for every little action. It was not intelligent it would just pop up for everything.

Comment: Annoying and secure are two entirely different things. Because more actions required authorization, Vista was more secure. It also gave *more* information for processes that did multiple things. Could it be an annoyance, that a matter of opinion... But it didn't detract from the security Vista had by default; The biggest problem with UAC is that most novice users learned quickly to ignore UAC.

Comment: By default Vista is more secure. But for a advanced user there is no difference.

Comment: @Devid that's utter nonsense. Even an expert has a lapse of judgement or makes mistakes. There is a reason no one turns off SUDO in Linux for example...

Comment: Yes, but under the hood there is nothing missing from Windows 7, that was not in Vista. It is just not that annoying any more. And as you mentioned many users quickly ignored the UAC in Vista because of its annoyance. If for every action you warn the user about a danger, when the danger comes the user want believe you and proceed with his actions. Microsoft if I remember right made a chart [in 2010] which was showing that the infection rates on Win7 are lower than those on Vista. The chart is in my original post.

Comment: @Devid that makes some sense, as people had more time to think about how to infect Windows XP than 7, because *7 came up after XP*.